Wrong Token on the send mail API on microsoft graph
I'm trying to use the send mail API using the Microsoft Graph API and I've tried it using the Graph API explorer and it's working fine but when I try to get the Token on Postman and get the token I get an error.
when I use the token from the explorer on my code it works fine but when using mine from Postman I got this error :
Response content: b'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.","innerError":{"date":"2024-05-28T11:34:23","request-id":"","client-request-id":""}}}'
import requests

url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail'

access_token = ''

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

email = {
   "message": {
       "subject": "PYTHON",
       "body": {
          "contentType": "HTML",
          "content": ""
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "hamzaha@watira.ai"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"saveToSentItems": "true"
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=email)

if response.status_code == 202:
   print("Email sent successfully.")
else:
  print("Failed to send email. Status code:", response.status_code)
  print("Response content:", response.content)




Replace /me with /users/userId while using token generated with client credentials flow and grant Mail.Send permission of Application type in Azure AD application.

@Sridevi and how can i get the userID ? and when I try to get the access token and paste it from the graph explorer it worked to the same one so I guess the problem is with the token itself

You can get user ID here: Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Users -> All users -> Select User -> Fing Object ID in Overview page

Graph Explorer uses Delegated flow that works with delegated permissions of signed-in user. But client credentials flow uses permissions of Application type. This won't work with /me endpoint.

The error occurred as /me endpoint supports only delegated flows like authorization code flow that involves user interaction, but client credentials is app-only flow.
Initially, I too got same error when I run the code passing token generated with client credentials flow like this:
import requests

url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail'
access_token = 'token'

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

email = {
   "message": {
       "subject": "PYTHON",
       "body": {
          "contentType": "HTML",
          "content": ""
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "sridevi.mxxx1@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"saveToSentItems": "true"
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=email)

if response.status_code == 202:
   print("Email sent successfully.")
   
else:
  print("Failed to send email. Status code:", response.status_code)
  print("Response content:", response.content)

Response:

To resolve the error, you need to either switch to delegated flows like authorization code flow for generating token or use /users/userID endpoint with client credentials token.
In my case, I granted Mail.Send permission of Application type in my app registration like this:

Now, I generated token using client credentials flow via Postman as below:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Response:

When I used this token in below Python code by changing endpoint to /users/userID, I got response like this:
import requests

url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userId/sendMail'
access_token = 'token'

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

email = {
   "message": {
       "subject": "PYTHON",
       "body": {
          "contentType": "HTML",
          "content": ""
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "sridevi.mxxx1@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"saveToSentItems": "true"
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=email)

if response.status_code == 202:
   print("Email sent successfully.")
   
else:
  print("Failed to send email. Status code:", response.status_code)
  print("Response content:", response.content)

Response:

You can find User ID of sender in Azure Portal like this:

This /me endpoint works in Graph Explorer as it uses delegated permissions of signed-in user. If you prefer switching to delegated flows for generating tokens, refer this similar SO thread I previously answered that includes token generation with authorization code flow:
azure active directory - Call microsoft graph  - Stack Overflow
